# use an export variable as part of filename in awk program

Tags: awk, environment-variables

I have set an `export X25DATAF=/home/Bob/X25/Datafiles` in my profile and that's what is outputted when I do a `echo $X25DATAF`.

I want to replace `/home/Bob/X25/Datafiles` in the `awk` below with the `$X25DATAF` in the 2 places it's in the `awk` program. But, I can't get it to work (ie: `$X25DATAF/ALL_SW_DB.txt`). This way all I have to do is set the `export` to the path on whichever system I'm on to run this `awk` program (and others like it).

```
awk -F"\t" ' 
FILENAME=="Sites1" {
  cllina[$0]=$0
}
FILENAME=="/home/bob/X25/DataFiles/ALL_SW_DB.txt" {
  swclli=hostclli=""
  swclli=substr($7,1,8)
  hostclli=substr($3,1,8)
  fclli[hostclli]++
  fclli[swclli]++

  if(hostclli==cllina[hostclli]) {
    if(swclli!=hostclli) {
      printf"REM|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s-%s\n",hostclli,$4,$3,$6,$9,$7,$12,$13,$5,$14 >>"host_remote"
    }
   }

  if(swclli==cllina[swclli]) {
      printf"HOST|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s-%s\n",swclli,$4,$3,$6,$9,$7,$12,$13,$5,$14 >>"host_remote"
    }
 }
 END{
  for(x in cllina)
    if(fclli[x]=="") printf"%s\n",x >"site1.err"
}' Sites1 /home/bob/X25/DataFiles/ALL_SW_DB.txt
```

Comment: if you only have 2 files, why not simply use `FILENAME!="Sites1"`. Or use the awk variable `ARGIND` which says which file you are looking at, 1 or 2.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but in your example, you can use `ARGV[2]` in `awk` program to get `/home/bob/X25/DataFiles/ALL_SW_DB.txt`, you passed it as second argument to your `awk`.

Answer (score 0):

As usual the construction `FNR==NR` (file row number is equal whole row number) is used for 1st file and `next` operation to skip 2nd file instructions:

```
awk -F'\t' -v OFS='|' '
    FNR==NR{
        cllina[$0]=1
        next
    }
    {
        swclli=hostclli=""
        …
        fclli[swclli]++
    }
    cllina[hostclli] && swclli!=hostclli{
        print "REM",hostclli,$4,$3,$6,$9,$7,$12,$13,$5,$14
    }
    cllina[swclli]{
        print "HOST",swclli,$4,$3,$6,$9,$7,$12,$13,$5,$14
    }
    …
    }' Sites1 /home/bob/X25/DataFiles/ALL_SW_DB.txt >>host_remote
```

or see comments to your question.

Comment: This is the whole code I have been using for 2 years. Several other user want to run it on their systems and that's why I want to substitute my export of X25DATAF=/home/Bob/X25/DATAFILES to replace the path name in the AWK prog for the file ALL_SW_DB.txt. I have several other AWKs that use different files but they all are in that same directory.

Comment: The code is too long for the comment by about 10 lines. The main question is how do I replace the /home/Bob/X25/Datafiles (the path to the ALL_SW_DB.txt) with the $X25DATAF I exported from my profile. All the other files are in whichever Dir the AWK is running from.

Comment: This is the end of the full AWK program

awk -F"|" ' BEGIN{
printf"H/R|BLDG_CLLI8|OLD_CMPY|HOST_CLLI|HOST_SW_TY|SWITCH_NAME|"
printf"SW_TYPE|SW_CLLI|SWITCH_ADDRESS|CITY|ST-ZIP\n"

}
FILENAME=="site1.err" {
  serr[$0]=$0
}
FILENAME=="/home/bob/X25/DataFiles/ALL_SW_DB.txt" {
  gsub("\\011","\174")
  clliswtyp[$7]=$9
}
FILENAME=="host_remote" {
  printf"%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s\n",$1,$2,$3,$4,clliswtyp[$4],$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10
}
END{
  for(y in serr)
    printf"HOST|%s|||||NONE||||\n",y
}' site1.err /home/bob/X25/DataFiles/ALL_SW_DB.txt host_remote >host_remote1

Comment: This reads a little better
awk -F"|" ' BEGIN{
printf"H/R|BLDG_CLLI8|OLD_CMPY|HOST_CLLI|HOST_SW_TY|SWITCH_NAME|"
printf"SW_TYPE|SW_CLLI|SWITCH_ADDRESS|CITY|ST-ZIP\n"

}
FILENAME=="site1.err" {
  serr[$0]=$0
}
FILENAME=="/home/bob/X25/DataFiles/ALL_SW_DB.txt" {
  gsub("\\011","\174")
  clliswtyp[$7]=$9
}
FILENAME=="host_remote" {
  printf"%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s\n",$1,$2,$3,$4,clliswtyp[$4],$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10
}
END{
  for(y in serr)
    printf"HOST|%s|||||NONE||||\n",y
}' site1.err /home/bob/X25/DataFiles/ALL_SW_DB.txt host_remote >host_remote1

Comment: awk -F"|" ' BEGIN{
printf"H/R|BLDG_CLLI8|OLD_CMPY|HOST_CLLI|HOST_SW_TY|SWITCH_NAME|"
printf"SW_TYPE|SW_CLLI|SWITCH_ADDRESS|CITY|ST-ZIP\n"

}
FILENAME=="site1.err" {
  serr[$0]=$0
}
FILENAME=="/home/bob/X25/DataFiles/ALL_SW_DB.txt" {
  gsub("\\011","\174")
  clliswtyp[$7]=$9
}
FILENAME=="host_remote" {
  printf"%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s|%s\n",$1,$2,$3,$4,clliswtyp[$4],$5,$6,$7,$8,$9,$10
}
END{
  for(y in serr)
    printf"HOST|%s|||||NONE||||\n",y
}' site1.err /home/bob/X25/DataFiles/ALL_SW_DB.txt host_remote >host_remote1

Sorry, this one does.

Comment: @BobEng I have no intention to read you code in comments to understand your goal. Try to explain what you want in question. Much better if you show example data and example of output.

Comment: I couldn't figure how to edit my question so I sent and script and data update as an answer if anyone can look at that and give me the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simpler example. I want to replace the 2 instances of `/home/Bob/X25/DataFiles` with the export of `X25DATAF` (`export X25DATAF=/home/Bob/X25/DataFiles`) I have in my profile. If I can get it to work in this simple `awk`, I can modify my real `awk`.

```
$ cat test1
test1_data
test1a_data
test1b_data
```

#### `Bob@Bob-PC ~/X25/Scott/TEST/TEST1`

```
$ cat /home/Bob/X25/DataFiles/test2
test2_data
```

#### `Bob@Bob-PC ~/X25/Scott/TEST/TEST1`

```
$ cat gettestfiles
```

File 1test11 has 3 records `test1_data`, `test1a_data` and `test1b_data` and is in same dir that `awk` is run in.

File `test2` only has 1 record `test2_data` and is in the `/home/Bob/X25/DataFiles` directory.

```
awk -F"_" '
FILENAME=="test1" {
  print $1 " " $2
}
FILENAME=="/home/bob/X25/DataFiles/test2" {
print $0
}
END{ }' test1 /home/bob/X25/DataFiles/test2
```

#### `Bob@Bob-PC ~/X25/Scott/TEST/TEST1`

```
$ gettestfiles
test1 data
test1a data
test1b data
test2_data
```

#### `Bob@Bob-PC ~/X25/Scott/TEST/TEST1`

```
$
```

Comment: I can't see a problem. `… FILENAME==ARGV[2]{…}' test1 "$X25DATAF/test2"` Or what you want to change?

Comment: works perfectly. I was trying to put the $X25DATAF after the filename== instead of using the ARGV. Thank you. How do I give you credit for setting me straight? I just joined this group.

Comment: But as stated in my answer `FNR==NR{…,next}…` is more suitable